# Google map is not being displayed when I install app from playstore

Tags: java, android, maps

I am working on google maps. I have generated the signed apk from my keystore and also SHA-1 from the same keystore. I have also put that SHA-1 to developer console. Now I have uploaded my application to playstore. When I test it after downloading application from playstore. Then map is not being displayed. When I checked logcat, it says Authorization Failed. When can be root cause. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue so what I do is as below:

1. Created a fresh copy of SHA-1 using the same Keystore(in Command Promt) and just added to the concern Map API.

   ```
   command : keytool -list -v -keystore ~\mykeystore.jks
   ```
2. Add generated SHA-1 to the Map API.

**Note: Make sure of using same keystore of release.**

Comment: What do you mean by **not fixed?

Comment: Means map is still not displaying

Comment: Yes, I have already tried all these steps before posting the question.

Comment: Once again can you go through the same steps.

Comment: Okay, if you are saying then let me try again.

Comment: If you are not bothering then can you give me your keystore I'll generate SHA-1 for that.

Comment: How can I give my keystore to you. means can you give me your email address ?

Comment: Check you email please

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate new Api key from your release SHA-1.And use it in your app.

Comment: I have also done the same, but problem has not been solved

Comment: as I said make sure you are using correct api key in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure below point.

1) Did you create map api key from your keystore's sha1  from which your are signing your application not debug key store.

2) Did you enable "Google Maps Android API" from the developer console https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/maps_android_backend/overview?project=linen-rex-463

3) Ensure you are creating the sha1 key from correct package. Because "authorization failed" enerally caused when your app's key is not being identified at google console.

3) Have you added the new MAP API key to your Application meta info.

Do let me know if you still face the same issue.

Comment: Yes believe me I have gone through all these steps. I am also worry that how it can possible that after performing all these steps map is not displaying

Comment: Then I would recommend you to create a new fresh key store and repeat all these steps. This seems like sha1 problem.